# React-xarrows: several arrows are placed one over each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xarrows

I use react-xarrows library in my project. Arrows connect tables in diagram. In some cases there are more then one link between two tables so arrows between them "lie" on each other and we can see only one link instead of 3 or 4.
Here's the part of my code:

```
const getArrows = () => {
        let arrows = [];

        diagram.areas?.map((area) => {
            area.foreignKeys?.map((link, key) => {                
                arrows.push(
                    <div >
                      <Xarrow
                        start={link.sourceTableName}
                        end={link.targetTableName}
                        path={"straight"} //
                        headShape={"arrow1"}
                        headSize={12}
                        startAnchor={startAnchorVariants}
                        endAnchor={endAnchorVariants}
                        zIndex={arrowIsShawn}
                        color={area.color}
                        strokeWidth={arrowWidth}
                        key={link.name}
                        passProps={{
                            onClick: (event) => onDeleteArrowHandler(link.name)
                        }}                        
                    />                      
                    </div>                    
                );
            });
        });
        return arrows;
    };
```

An array with tables I get in area.tables?.map ...

I tried to render several components of Xarrow with different endAnchors, but then I see more arrows then it should be between table components.

```
let endAnchorVariants = {};
                let startAnchorVariants = {};
                switch (key % 3) {
                    case 0:
                        startAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { x: 12 }
                        };
                        endAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { x: 7 }
                        };
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { y: 12 }
                        };
                        endAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { y: 7 }
                        };
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        startAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { y: 12 }
                        }
                        endAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { y: 12 }
                        };
                        break;
                    default:
                        startAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { x: 6 }
                        };
                        endAnchorVariants = {
                            position: "auto",
                            offset: { x: 4 }
                        };
```

With these offsets arrows are still close to each other, I need another solution. How can I make all the arrows between same tables visible?

Answer (score 0):

i've used xarrows in several projects, what does your area.tables look like, and are you possibly rendering several times?

Also, you could try applying an id property to the arrows and on your start and end anchors you could try and use an x or y offset to help troubleshoot and see where you are double rendering:

```
       <Xarrow
        arrowBodyProps={{ style: {opacity: opVal}, onClick: (e) => ArrowModal(e, arrows[index].id), id: "arrow" + arrows[index].id }}
        arrowHeadProps={{ style: {opacity: opVal}, onClick: (e) => ArrowModal(e, arrows[index].id), id: "arrowhead" + arrows[index].id }}
        key={arrows[index].id}
        divContainerStyle={{position: "relative"}}
        SVGcanvasStyle={{position: "relative"}}
        SVGcanvasProps={{id: "SVG"+arrows[index].id}}
        color={arrows[index].color}
        dashness={arrows[index].dashness}
        end={arrows[index].end}
        endAnchor={arrows[index].endAnchor}
        gridBreak={arrows[index].gridBreak}
        headSize={4}
        path={arrows[index].path}
        showHead={true}
        start={arrows[index].start}
        startAnchor={arrows[index].startAnchor}
        strokeWidth={arrows[index].strokeWidth}
        zIndex={10}
      />
```

Comment: I don't render arrows several times. Different anchors do not help much. How can id property help?  Which xarrow prop can place them in different places between same tables? arrowBodyProps? I didn't get it from your answer((

Comment: Maybe you know another library in React. I need to draw lines between draggable tables. And sometimes there are three or four links between those tables

Comment: The startAnchor and endAnchor mod the points.. react-archer also provides a similar capability.  But I really think the issue is with the object you are mapping to xarrow

Comment: what do you mean "object you are mapping to xarrow"?

Comment: In my project I render one object Diagram. there are several arrays with Areas inside. And inside Area there are two arrays: tables and foreignKeys. I use react-xarrows for foreign keys. Each object in this array has 1. source table name (start point); 2. target table name (end point) and 3. name. That is how I connect tables. Names are unique even it connects same tables